# NAS not showing up in network automatically during VPN connection

Tags: vpn, nas, home-networking

I have a NAS connected to my home network with the files I want to access, and a VPN setup (PPTP and openVPN too) for site-to-site connection. When I connect to my VPN from an external network, the NAS does not show up in the network, despite it is there. If I type \\192.168.0.132 (ip of the NAS on the local network) to the file browser on windows, everything works fine, the route shows up in the network, and I can connect to the NAS. However it is not at all intuitive, and I would like to see my NAS on its own configured name in the network immediately after connection without having to explicitly tell the file browser where to find it.

Is this possible with some configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a small network situation and you know the connection works (local IP works), use a HOSTS file on the machine you are working on to associate IP address with HOST name on the target device.

Example from a working HOSTS file

> Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
> lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>   102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
>    38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
> ```
>
> localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> 192.168.x.y   drivename       # description
>
> 192.168.x.z   drivename2      # description 2

Once done, you will still have to map the drive, or create a batch file on the desktop with the mapping.

I use HOSTS files because it is not worth implementing DNS tools to ensure the association.

**Note**:  the comment (octothorpe character) in the HOSTS file example was interpreted as Bold. So find your local HOSTS file, edit by running Notepad as Administrator, make changes for your stuff and save as same name.

Comment: Thanks! And can you tell me the why? Why is that through VPN it cannot do the connection automatically, while locally it can?

Comment: If you are Local, then you are on the same network (locally) and no need to do the association in HOSTS. If the machine is remote, it does not know about the other (NAS) end local addressing, so you need to make the association. I have done this remote work for a while and the association technique works fine.

Comment: @daniel The NAS is "known" to your laptop because it broadcasts its presence once in a while on the local network. Your laptop will pick this up automatically when it is in the same LAN. This broadcast, in most cases, doesn't propagate across routers/VPNs. (It is a bit more complicated than that, but this space is to short for the whole story.) You can't fix the broadcast problem. But you can simply make a shortcut to the NAS or pin it to "Quick Access" in Explorer if you stick the ip-address in the HOSTS file.

Comment: You need to run Notepad as Admin to change the file and for this to work.